# Best way to access external JavaScript file and place contents in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So, lets say you have a page that wants to load from a javascript file and it includes

temp.html file

```
<script src="example.js"></script>
<p class="one"></p>
```

Now in the example.js file you have a function that is

```
    function getInfo() {
    var place = "foo"
    $(".one").html(place);
    }
//Edit currently I call the function inside the JS file
```

`getInfo();`

My question is how would you connect the two files so that the external javascript file knows that it is pointed to the paragraph with the class one? 
Normally when this is in a single page, you would call the function and the info will be set. 
I have seen a getScript method and a load method for Jquery. Would that be applicable here?
Any ideas on how to approach this? If you provide some code that will be super helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: **When** do you want `getInfo()` to be called?

Comment: @PM77-1 I want it to be called inside the js file. I currently have the getInfo() called after the function.. I don't know if its smarter to call it from the temp file

Comment: You have not answered my question. Please read it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to execute `getInfo()` as soon as it's defined (i.e.: `example.js` is loaded).

You can try this approach:

```
<script src="example.js" onload="getInfo();"></script>
```

In your **example.js**, change `getInfo()` to something like this:

```
function getInfo() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var place = "foo"
      $(".one").html(place);
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is a working way as well. Thanks for this!

Comment: @Jason Please accept one of the answers which works the best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your language is confusing, but you could use jQuery's $(document).ready function which would suffice.  Generally speaking, an externally loaded file should execute where the tag is in the script.

A hack could be to place a tag before the end of your document body, give it an id, and then use $('#id').ready() there.  In general though, you could just try coding the transclusion concept (I'm guessing you're used to this) from scratch using intervals and timeouts.

```
    <div id="rdy">
    </div>
</body>
```

Then in your file:

```
   $('#rdy').ready(getInfo);
```

Just my added opinion, you should consider that Google is up to some not-so-nice things these days, they are long-gone from the "do no evil" mantra.

Comment: Sorry about the language but it's just one of those things where I don't understand what to do

Comment: You've got the general hang of it, you're talking about having the DOM updated when the script runs but making sure your HTML is loaded first -- it would be a tutorial length, but I could describe to you how to set up a "setInterval" to check for changes in your document length.  You'd run your functions from there, but this would get tricky the more places you're trying to update.  Highly recommend [mustache.js](http://mustache.github.io/) for this sort of thing.

Comment: its funny because when i just tried this on one page, I did have setInterval implemented and everything was working. Now however, nothing seems to work and I'm confused as hell

Comment: haha, run "getInfo()" in your browser console and what happens then?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume you have a JavaScript file that contains this content:

```
function getInfo() {
    var place = "foo"
    $(".one").html(place);
}
```

then your markup will look something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="example.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                getInfo();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="one"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

`$(function(){ ... });` is just the simplified version of `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`. They both more or less handle the [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload) event, which fires when page has finished loading.

Comment: Tieson, I still am not able to get anything from this code. Are you having the same issue? I am wondering if its because it can't recognize the html method or something

Comment: Well, it _is_ missing a reference to the jQuery library, so it won't work as-is. I've updated the example to include a CDN reference.

Comment: Great. this is all working, do you think you can add implement another feature to this and see if it works?

Comment: @Jason I suggest you take a stab at whatever you're trying to accomplish first, and if/when you get stuck, _then_ ask another question. You can always reference your previous question in the new one, if it's helpful to understanding the context of the new question.