# getJSON url method doesn't work when called from external javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

This is a complex issue and I am wondering if this is more related with JSONP (JSON + padding) or not.

So there is a file called example.php

```
<script src="jquery.js"</script>
<script src="example.js" onload="getInfo();"></script>

<p class="one"></p>
```

Now in the example.js file, I use the getJSON method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   function getInfo() {
        $.getJSON("URL", function(data) {
        var name = [parses through the json data];
        $("p.one").html(name);
```

This does't work however if it is not involving an external JSON file it works. 
Here is a previous question that was answered: [Best way to access external JavaScript file and place contents in div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942191/best-way-to-access-external-javascript-file-and-place-contents-in-div) 
Curious to know if anyone else has faced this problem and I haven't been able to find anything by Google or on StackOverflow on this.

Comment: It the file is on another domain, the same-origin policy prohibits you from getting the file, and there's basically only two workarounds, CORS or JSONP, both has to be implemented on the server you're getting the file from, and if it's not there's nothing you can do in your clientside script.

Comment: So it doesn't matter if it is in an external Javascript file? It is working when I place everything in one file.

Comment: When your script is in an external JS file, you are probably calling the function too soon before the DOM is loaded, thus p.one does not exist yet so the ajax call runs, but fails to put the results anywhere.

Comment: So it's not external JSON or JSONP, it's just that you're doing something strange with the onload handler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your script calling syntax as follows. Remove `onload` attribue. There is no attribute `onload` for `script` tag

```
<script src="example.js"></script>
```

And, your `example.js` file look like this. You may call the `getInfo()` method in that file also

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   function getInfo() {
        $.getJSON("URL", function(data) {
        var name = [parses through the json data];
        $("p.one").html(name);
        });
   }

   getInfo();
});
```

Comment: holy crap, can you tell me how why this works? I'm very curious to know!

Comment: its weird because if you see the link that I posted for a question earlier someone did have the onload attribute on the script tag and it seemed to work.

Comment: Check this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp ..and I did not heard about the onload attribute for script tag.

Comment: also Asik do you know why you have to have the $(document).ready method? I understand that it executes once the DOM is loaded but when you don't have that what difference does that make? It seems like it just doesn't work at all without that

Comment: you are updating the DOM (p.one) after ajax response..In your case, it works without document.ready. so it means, it takes some time to update dom within that time page gets loaded.

Comment: thanks for the help! you helped save me a lot of time!